# How can I find the first commit of a branch using Gitlab API?

Tags: api, gitlab-api

Currently, I am trying the below command. But it is sorted by the last commit. I need to get the first commit on the branch using Gitlab API

[https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{projectid}/repository/commits?ref_name={branch_name}&per_page=1](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/%7Bprojectid%7D/repository/commits?ref_name=%7Bbranch_name%7D&per_page=1)